# Calculate file checksum in JS using ReadableStream and PipeTo?

Tags: javascript, checksum, cryptojs, fileapi, streams-api

I wish to calculate a file's checksum locally with `JS` and have been searching for examples of how to accomplish this using the `Streams Api` and [`pipeTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/pipeTo), but have only found examples with `Node.js` which I am not familiar with. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
var stream = file.stream();
var hash = CryptoJS.algo.SHA1.create();
await stream.pipeTo(hash);
console.log(hash);
```

This code does not work since `CryptoJS` doesn't seem to create [`WriteableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream). Can I wrap what `CryptoJS` creates in some kind of shim or sink? Other suggestions?

I could read and append buffers incrementally of course, but the code becomes a bit messy so I was hoping I could leverage `pipeTo` to avoid complicating the code.

Comment: Node.js provides helpers to convert web streams to Node streams and vice versa. e.g. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamwritabletowebstreamwritable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function byteArrayToWordArray(ba) {
    let wa = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) wa[(i / 4) | 0] |= ba[i] << (24 - 8 * i);
    return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(wa, ba.length);
}

const cryptoJsWritableStream = (hash) => {
  return new WritableStream({
    write(chunk) {
      hash.update(byteArrayToWordArray(chunk));
    },
    close() {},
    abort() {},
  });
};

const stream = file.stream();
const hash = CryptoJS.algo.SHA1.create();
await stream.pipeTo(cryptoJsWritableStream(hash));
console.log(hash.finalize().toString());
```